# RxJava - How to continue background task after unsubscribing from observable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Im new to RxJava . I have a `bitmapObservable` for a simple network operation of downloading a list of image urls and convert it to bitmaps.

```
mSubscription = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap[]>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Bitmap[]> subscriber) {
            String[] urls = new String[]{
                    "http://www.convertimage.net/frontframe/images/cute_ball_info.png",
                    "http://customerserviceai.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/waiting.png",
                    "https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"};
            Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[urls.length];
            int i = 0;
            for (String url : urls) {
                final Bitmap bitmap = Downloader.getBitmapFromURL(url);
                if (bitmap == null) {
                    subscriber.onError(new IOException());
                } else {
                    bitmaps[i++] = bitmap;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap " + url + " downloaded" + bitmap);
                }
            }
            subscriber.onNext(bitmaps);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Bitmap[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Everything completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Some error has been occured");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Bitmap[] bitmaps) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Downloaded bitmaps " + bitmaps);
                }
            });
```

on the `onDestroy` of activity , I'm unsubscribing to the observable to avoid memory leaks.

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

What I can see is , if I go out of the activity during the image download process , the background task also got killed. I just want to continue the backgroung task , even if I've unsubscribed from the observer. Is it possible?

Comment: you cant do that, if you unsubscribe your observable

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an RxJava question. In Android if you want your background task to exist even after Activity dies you can use Service. There's two kind of service, background and foreground Service.

But Background Service is not enough, Android doesn't guarantee your app won't be killed if it runs on Background. Ian Lake explain it nicely in  [his blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f#.xuuteda3q).

So, in order to make sure your app keep Downloading you can use Foreground Service. This pattern is typically used in Music Player app, where even after user lock the screen, you can still hear music in the background because the app is still running in the background.

However, if you still want to use RxJava to solve your problem, you can use Subject. Save your download progress on Subject and when you want to continue download, just emit your Observable again.

Comment: Ok. `In Android if you want your background task to exist even after Activity dies you can use Service` . But in AsynkTask we do have an option for this right , using `AsyncTask.cancel(true);`  That's why I was searching for any equivalent option in Rx

Comment: ```AsyncTask.cancel(true)``` doesn't cancel your task immediately and the implementation is yours to make. You still have to check isCancelled periodically and cancel your task when it's cancelled.

Comment: I mean `AsyncTask.cancel(false);`  option, if you use this `false` option , in-progress tasks are allowed to complete right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why are we talking about AsyncTask?

Comment: I was just pointing a feature of AsynkTask , which is exactly what I wanted to achieve using Rx